# Why is Bayesian error concave down as a function of prior P(w1)?

Tags: bayes

Given a two categorization problem, why Bayesian error is concave down as a function of prior $P(w_1)$?

$w_1$, $w_2$ are two underlying concepts with prior $P(w_1)$ and $P(w_2)$. We observe the evidence $x$, which is related to $w_1$ and $w_2$ through conditional probability $p(x|w_1)$ and $p(x|w_2)$.

Based on $x$, we will do action $a_1$ or $a_2$, and the cost according to each action is $c(a_i|w_j)$, i.e. $c(a_1|w_1)=0$ (guess correctly) and $c(a_2|w_1)=1$ (guess wrong).

And finally Bayes error is the expectation of $\text{cost}(\text{action}|x)$.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in the notation--for instance, what is "c2"?--but overall it seems to me that if by "P(w1)" you mean a single *number* giving the prior chance of "w1", that "w1" and "w2" are the only two possible prior values, and the "action" is tantamount to guessing whether "w1" or "w2" holds--then the Bayes error is a *linear* function of the P(wi).  Because that is trivially concave down (*and* concave up!), I wonder whether I might be misinterpreting this question. Could you set me straight?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I'm trying to understand this graph https://www.dropbox.com/s/me9g0edcznqlr4o/Screenshot%20%284%29.png Can you elaborate why Bayes error is a linear function of P(w1)?

Comment: I suspect that plot is for a generic convex loss function.

Comment: thanks! Can you please tell me why Bayes error is linear wrt P(w1)?